# How to make a count formula in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, count

I'm trying to learn javascript and properly get my head around it i need to create a count function that takes two parameters and returns them, not display them.

If count (0,10); was called, the function would return the following string:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

If count (2,5) was called, the function would return the following string:
2,3,4,5

this is essentially what I'm looking to do but I'm not even sure where to begin with this and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use a simple loop with first index as lowest value and check for highest value in condition, `for(let i=least value, i<= highest value; i++)` did you tried anything ? if yes please add the code also in question

Comment: Like i said, I'm not really sure where to begin because i believe I would need loops, string manipulation and probably an if statement

Comment: Yes you need loop and condition to check whether put `,` in between or not, and a varibale

Answer (score 0):

A for loop should do it but if your really need it to be in a function you can doit something like that.

```
function count(low,high) {
  out = ''
  for (let i = low; i<= high; i++){
    out = out + i.toString();
  }
  return out
}
```

Comment: You still need to add the commas

Answer (score 0):

```js
function count(initalCount, endCount) {
  for (let i = initalCount; i <= endCount; i++) {
    // your code here
    console.log(i)
  }
}

count(2, 10);
```